# On radio button click, show/hid divs with dynamicaly changed IDs or classes

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, laravel-5

```
<div class="">
    @foreach($result->package as $package) //listing all packages from DB using Laravel's Blade template
        <input id="id_radio{{$package->id}}" type="radio" value="{{$package->id}}" name="radio"
        >{{$package->name}} <br>
        <div class="" id="package{{$package->id}}">
            @foreach($package->price_option as $price_option)
                Price Option: <input type="radio" value="{{$price_option->id}}"
                                     name="radio">{{$price_option->id}}  <br>
                <div class="">
                    @foreach($price_option->values as $value)
                        Values: {{$value->value}} <br>
                    @endforeach
                </div>
            @endforeach
        </div>
    @endforeach
</div>
```

Page Source:

```
<div class="">
  <input id="id_radio22" type="radio" value="22" name="radio"
    >Package 1 <br>
  <div class="" id="package22">
      Price Option: <input type="radio" value="75"
                           name="radio">75  <br>
      <div class="">
          Values: Dummy text <br>
          Values: Dummy text 2 <br>
      </div>
      Price Option: <input type="radio" value="78"
                           name="radio">78  <br>
      <div class="">
          Values: Dummy text <br>
          Values: Dummy text 2 <br>
      </div>
  </div>
  <input id="id_radio23" type="radio" value="23" name="radio"
  >Package 2 <br>
  <div class="" id="package23">
      Price Option: <input type="radio" value="76"
                           name="radio">76  <br>
      <div class="">
          Values: a <br>
           Values: b <br>
          Values: c <br>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

What I need is to show all price options as radio buttons when I click on, for example, package 1 radio button, and to show all price options as radio buttons for package2 but at the same time hide price options of `Package1`.

Then for all Price Options that I click to show all Values that belongs to that Price Option.

Currently dont have any CSS or JQuery/JavaScript code

Comment: Share parsed HTML than `php` wrapped HTML

Comment: I dont understand what do you mean? :(

Comment: @RayonDabre meant that instead of show us your `php` code with `@foreach` for example, show us the `html` which sent to the browser (without `php` syntax of course)

Comment: @RayonDabre Here it is. I left class and id empty for purpose, so you can name them as you wish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[Working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jnwrc5ay/77/)**.

Try to hide all the `div`s (that have id start with `package`) bellong to the other `radio` buttons then show just the div belong to the clicked one :

```
$('div[id^="package"]').hide();

$('body').on('click','input[id^="id_radio"]',function(){
    $('div[id^="package"]').hide();
    $('#package'+$(this).val()).show();
});

$('div[id^="price_option_div"]').hide();

$('body').on('click','.price_option',function(){
    $('div[id^="price_option_div_"]').hide();
    $("#price_option_div_"+$(this).val()).show();
});
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I updated my post with page source code. It may be more clear what i need to show. And I explained it to @RajivRisi bellow